# Is it possible to use variables and data in in-template css properties?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<td style="width:77px" id="<%=id%>">
     <div class="condbar">
          <div  class="condprogress" style="width:Data.condition%; background:condColor"></div>
          <div class="condvalue"><%=condition%><span>%</span></div>
      </div>
</td>
```

I want to set the width of a div .roster_condprogress as a percentage according to data and change the color accordingly (using a variable for that). What is a correct way to write this? (if it exists)

Comment: Presumably you would interpolate your variables in, exactly like you're doing with `<%=id%>`.

Comment: You're already doing _almost_ what you're asking with `id="<%=id%>"`. Do the same thing in a `style=""` attribute - not that I necessarily recommend using inline styles in a general sense. It wouldn't hurt to add a tag to your question for whatever server-side language that is (JSP? ASP?).